# Generating Random Combinations of Dictionary Key and Value Sets

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a program to sort through a music library file. I have this one particular function, generateRandomPlaylist(musicLibDictionary), that I am stuck on.

The function needs to randomly pick a key from the dictionary and randomly assign one of the values to the key. For instance the artists in the dictionary include The Who, Adele and The Beatles. The respective albums include Tommy; 19, 21, 25; Abbey Road, Let It Be. I need the program to randomly pick one of the keys (the artists) and then randomly pick one of the key's values. The randomly generated playlist needs to have all three artists, not repeats, but different albums from the artist. The way I have it set up, the output doesn't necessarily use all three artists. Sample output should look like:

```
Here is your random playlist:
- 25 by Adele
- Abbey Road by The Beatles
- Tommy by The Who
```

Each time the function is called, the playlist should be different. Like I said, right now the function doesn't run properly, and I also get a printing error saying I cannot concatenate a list and a string, so I don't know where I am going wrong.

The code for the program is below:

```
# importing pickle
import pickle
import random

# declaration of functions
def displayMenu():
    print("Welcome to Your Music Library")
    print("Options:")
    print("\t1) Display Library")
    print("\t2) Display all artists")
    print("\t3) Add an album")
    print("\t4) Delete an album")
    print("\t5) Delete an artist")
    print("\t6) Search Library")
    print("\t7) Generate a random playlist")
    print("\t8) Make your own playlist")
    print("\t9) Exit")

def displayLibrary(musicLibDictionary):
    for key in musicLibDictionary:
        print("Artist: " + key)
        print("Albums: ")
        for album in musicLibDictionary[key]:
            print("\t- " + album)

def displayArtists(musicLibDictionary):
    print("Displaying all artists:")
    for key in musicLibDictionary:
        print(" - " + key)

def addAlbum(musicLibDictionary):
    artistName = input("Please enter the name of the artist you would like to add: ")
    albumName = input("Please enter the name of the album you would like to add: ")
    if artistName in musicLibDictionary.keys():
        musicLibDictionary[artistName].append(albumName)
    else:
        musicLibDictionary[artistName] = [albumName]

def deleteAlbum(musicLibDictionary):
    artist = input("Enter artist: ")
    albumToBeDeleted = input("Enter album: ")
    if artist in musicLibDictionary.keys():
        if albumToBeDeleted in musicLibDictionary[artist]:
            musicLibDictionary[artist].remove(albumToBeDeleted)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

def deleteArtist(musicLibDct):
    artistToBeDeleted = input("Enter artist to delete: ")
    if artistToBeDeleted in musicLibDct.keys():
        del musicLibDct[artistToBeDeleted]
        return True
    else:
        return False

def searchLibrary(musicLibDictionary):
    searchTerm = input("Please enter a search term: ")
    searchTerm = searchTerm.lower()
    print("Artists containing" + searchTerm)
    for key in musicLibDictionary.keys():
        if searchTerm.lower() in key.lower():
            print("\t - ", end="")
            print(key)
    print("Albums containing" + searchTerm)
    for album in musicLibDictionary[key]:
        print("\t- " + album)

    for key in musicLibDictionary.keys():
        for album in musicLibDictionary[key]:
            if searchTerm in album.lower():
                print("\t - ", end="")
                print(album)

def generateRandomPlaylist(musicLibDictionary):
    print("Here is your random playlist:")
    for artist in musicLibDictionary.keys():
        artistSelection = random.choice(list(musicLibDictionary.keys()))
        albumSelection = random.choice(list(musicLibDictionary.values()))
    print("\t-" + albumSelection + "by" + artistSelection)


def loadLibrary(libraryFileName):
    fileIn = open(libraryFileName, "rb")
    val = pickle.load(fileIn)
    val = dict(val)
    return val

def saveLibrary(libraryFileName, musicLibDictionary):
    fileIn = open(libraryFileName, "wb")
    pickle.dump(musicLibDictionary, fileIn)

def main():
    musicLib = loadLibrary("musicLibrary.dat")
    userChoice = ""
    while (userChoice != 7):
        displayMenu()
        userChoice = int(input("> "))
        if userChoice == 1:
            displayLibrary(musicLib)
        elif userChoice == 2:
            displayArtists(musicLib)
        elif userChoice == 3:
            addAlbum(musicLib)
        elif userChoice == 4:
            deleteAlbum(musicLib)
        elif userChoice == 5:
            deleteArtist(musicLib)
        elif userChoice == 6:
            searchLibrary(musicLib)
        elif userChoice == 7:
            generateRandomPlaylist(musicLib)
        elif userChoice == 8:
            saveLibrary("musicLibrary.dat", musicLib)


# Call main
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, **if I understand correctly that you want each artist exactly once in a random order and a random album from each artist**:

```py
def generateRandomPlaylist(musicLibDictionary):
    print("Here is your random playlist:")
    artists = list(musicLibDictionary.keys())
    random.shuffle(artists)  # Perform an in-place shuffle
    for artistSelection in artists:
        albumSelection = random.choice(list(musicLibDictionary[artistSelection]))
        print("\t-" + albumSelection + "by" + artistSelection)
```

We know we want all the artists exactly once, but in a random order. Since the keys of the dictionary are the artists, then we can just perform a `random.shuffle` on the keys to get a random ordering of the artists. Then we have to look into each artist's albums (`musicLibDictionary[artist]`) and make a `random.choice` to pick out one album at random.

**What your code is doing, on a line by line basis, is the following**:

```py
def generateRandomPlaylist(musicLibDictionary):
    print("Here is your random playlist:")
    for artist in musicLibDictionary.keys(): # For each artist
        artistSelection = random.choice(list(musicLibDictionary.keys()))  # Choose one artist randomly (not necessarily the one in your for loop)
        albumSelection = random.choice(list(musicLibDictionary.values()))  # Choose a random album list (musicLibDictionary.values() returns a list of lists, so you're just choosing a random discography (list) from a random artist)
    print("\t-" + albumSelection + "by" + artistSelection)  # Because this is not indented into your loop, you're likely only getting the last one chosen
```

The reason you were getting issues appending a string and a list (not allowed in python directly, you must cast the list to a string first) is that your `albumSelection` variable was a full list of the albums from a random artist, not necessarily even the artist in the `artistSelection` variable. Your `musicLibDictionary.values()` was returning something like `[['Tommy'], ['19', '21', '25'], ['Abbey Road', 'Let It Be']]`. `random.choice` picks a random value out of the list provided to it so given a list like `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` it could pick out `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: I tried your code, and got the following error: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 278, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: Ah, looks like we do need to convert it to a list. I will update the answer.

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: That was the new error I got. I appreciate your help, I'm still new and understanding these errors and little details is still something I am working on

Comment: for artistSelection in random.shuffle(list(musicLibDictionary.keys())):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Ah, I forgot that shuffle doesn't return anything and performs the shuffle in-place. I will re-update. Sorry, I wasn't in a place to test it fully.

Comment: Updated to fix that issue, sorry for that. I have been able to test it now, and it should work. To be safe, you could, for your print do: `print("\t-" + str(albumSelection) + "by" + str(artistSelection))`, but that's hopefully not necessary

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!